# Difference in score to next rank

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe

```
  Group Score Rank
   1     0     3
   1     4     1
   1     2     2
   2     3     2
   2     1     3
   2     7     1
```

I have to take the difference of the score in next rank within each group. For example, in group 1  rank(1) - rank(2) = 4 - 2

Expected output:

```
    Group Score Rank  Difference
    1     0     3        0
    1     4     1        2
    1     2     2        2
    2     3     2        2
    2     1     3        0
    2     7     1        4
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? Show your code and ask question about specific problem with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Group', 'Rank'],ascending = [True,False])
df['Difference'] =df.groupby('Group', as_index=False)['Score'].transform('diff').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Group  Score  Rank  Difference
0      1      0     3           0
2      1      2     2           2
1      1      4     1           2
4      2      1     3           0
3      2      3     2           2
5      2      7     1           4
```

NOTE: The result is sorted based on the `rank` column.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a new column for the values in the next rank by using the shift() and then calculate the difference. You can see the following codes:

```
# Sort the dataframe
df = df.sort_values(['Group','Rank']).reset_index(drop=True)

# Shift up values by one row within a group
df['Score_next'] = df.groupby('Group')['Score'].shift(-1).fillna(0)

# Calculate the difference
df['Difference'] = df['Score'] - df['Score_next']
```

Here is the result:

```
print(df)

   Group  Score  Rank  Score_next  Difference
0      1      4     1         2.0         2.0
1      1      2     2         0.0         2.0
2      1      0     3         0.0         0.0
3      2      7     1         3.0         4.0
4      2      3     2         1.0         2.0
5      2      1     3         0.0         1.0
```